# MongoDB with Java - massive id query with performance concern

Tags: java, mongodb, time-complexity

I am using MongoDB with Apache Storm(Java) to process massive log files. Logs come from Radius, which is a statistic tool to collect user connection data, including username, signals like `Start`, `Interim-Update` and `Stop`(marking the start, the continuous state, and the end of a connection session). We have a bolt, and its goal is to persist/update (in its `execute()` method) documents with format like below:

```
{                                                                  
        "_id" : ObjectId("5a5f376911e55a36342e986f"),              
        "timestamp_hour" : ISODate("2017-05-09T10:00:00Z"),        
        "userid" : "4565465@xxx",                           
        "type" : "user_balance_time",                              
        "balances" : {                                             
                "3275" : {                                         
                        "input" : 0,                               
                        "output" : 0                               
                },                                                 
                "3469" : {                                         
                        "input" : 34944,                           
                        "output" : 122572                          
                }                                                  
        }                                                          
}
```

The part that matters is the `balances` part. `3275` stands for at which second (0-3600) the log comes in, and `input` stands for data in bytes downloaded from last line of data to this moment, `output` for upload.

Here comes the question: if, for any reason, for example, DST time transitional hour (when the time jumps backwards for an hour, which happens every year for my timezone, CET/CEST) in winter, or, if we receive three lines of log within the same seconds for the same user, what to do?

If the second is different, we add a sub-document, with no doubt; but if the second is the same, we must retrieve this document and update the sub-document `{'balances':{seconds: {input:xxx, output: xxx}}}` line, to save the later values.

The `execute()` method is the central part of this bolt, and will run millions of times every day, so, the repetition may comes more often than we imagine. Now, I am doing this query with `_id` previously saved, to keep it as quick as possible (I suppose the time is O(1), correct me if I am wrong). But I am wondering if it is the best way. I want to do as little query as possible; it is said to be expensive.

I doubt if we change interchange space for time(saving the retrieved data into memory for quick search); I don't see any necessity because at last we will have a copy of DB in memory, when to release it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this moment, I have change the code, to do as less queries as possible.

- First, search the DB with `userid` and `timestamp_hour`;
- If not found, insert, fin.
- If found, retrieve the first, get seconds data.

  - If does not coincide with current tuple's data, update;
  - If yes, do summing up of previous data and data of this second. (with `$inc`)

At the worst case, we have two queries (one initial, one of update, because `collection.update(filter, update)` comes with a query)

So the performance of ID retrieving is not a concern anymore.